Hide events post in Wordpress after certain date
I currently have an events section with a heading and upcoming events below that. The events hide after their date passes but when there are no events displayed the heading is still visible. I want the whole section to not be visible when there are no posts but because the WP_Query still recognizes that there are posts the heading is visible. Can you include the is statement to check the event date against the current date with the WP_Qurey?
<?php
    $current_date = date('F j, Y');
    $current_date = strtotime( $current_date );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'showposts' => 4,
        'meta_key'=>'event_date',  
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',   
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
<?php while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) : $events_query->the_post(); ?>
// If older than the current date, hide posts
<?php 
   $event_date = get_field('event_date');
   $event_date = strtotime( $event_date );
   if( $event_date > $current_date ):
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">View</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>


Check out this: https://3v4l.org/EtnV2. It loops from 0 to 9, but skips things less than 6 and outputs the header one time. The $headerShown variable is called a “flag”

Also, although I’m not as big a fan because of SEO and a11y issues, you can achieve this with modern CSS: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/OJGeKGJ

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters - there is even an example quite specifically for this, event_date getting checked against the current date.
